# Returning the Wear counter from a disk

Tags: powershell, disk

Just trying to automate some things for my job and I need to report the wear to a txt file that I can later compile into a report that gets emailed.

Having some trouble with getting it to populate the txt file with the wear indication, below is what I'm running and it gives me the variable I want to export to a file

```
Get-Disk | Where-Object {$_.IsBoot -eq 'True'} | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter | Select Wear
```

Below is what I'm running that generates the file I need but doesn't actually fill with anything

```
$DiskWear = Get-Disk | Where-Object {$_.IsBoot -eq 'True'} | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter | Select Wear
$DiskWear.Trim > trimmed.txt
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Did you mean `$DiskWear.Wear > trimmed.txt` ?

Comment: `Wear` is not a `string` property (it's a `byte` type), so doesn't have a `trim()` method.  Also, calling `trim` without parentheses makes PowerShell assume it's a property and if a property does not exist PowerShell doesn't consider it a error, so you get nothing, not even an exception.